# small flier with lualatex

Tags: header-footer, alignment, leaflet

here is my code for a flier:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=20mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
\pagestyle{empty}
\changefontsize{24}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=70mm]{example-image-10x16}
\hfill
\includegraphics[height=70mm]{example-image-10x16}

\begin{center}
    \begin{bfseries}
    {\LARGErrr My title}\\
    \end{bfseries}
\end{center}

\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    purpose of this flier (like "annual meeting", "anniversary"...)
\end{minipage}

\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ...anything like "no fees required"
        \item ..."transports for free" ...
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    "venue", "date", "time"???
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This document is for an a5 size flier (2 pages as i will repeat the code for another language, like french of spanish...). Here with the `article` class I get warnings for annotation space if I reduce furthermore the margins:

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 88.9583pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{88.9583pt}.
```

I also have to add some code to avoid the page number. What document class would be more appropriate for such purpose?

The two images at the top, i'd like to have them in the header part. This way i wouldn't need to include them again for the second page. With `fancyhdr` in `\fancyhead[L/R]{...}` they are aligned with the first line "My title" below the top margin.

Also could anyone do something to make the list being vertically centered between the two rules? right now the is more space at the bottom of the list.

EDIT: i forgot to put the two horizontal rules in my mwe. Now it's done.

Comment: You can try leaflet https://ctan.org/pkg/leaflet, or flowfram https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram .

Comment: Your code doesn't use `fancyhdr`, so you can't get a `fancyhdr` warning. Please give us the real code or the real warnings.

Comment: And, by the way, if you get a `fancyhdr` warning, do what it says `\setlength{\headheight}{88.9583pt}`.

Comment: well i said "IF I reduce furthermore...". Actually that problem with `\headheight` is resolved since now i'm adjusting it manually. Now I discovered that the change in `\headheight` does not affect `\textheight`, therefore, if `\headheight` is set too big, the footer is out of the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the definition of `headheight` in the geometry parameters, and use `includehead` so that it will adjust `textheight`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=20mm,hmargin=20mm,headheight=203pt,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
\pagestyle{empty}
\changefontsize{24}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=70mm]{example-image-10x16}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=70mm]{example-image-10x16}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{bfseries}
    {\LARGErrr My title}\\
    \end{bfseries}
\end{center}

\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    purpose of this flier (like "annual meeting", "anniversary"...)
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ...anything like "no fees required"
        \item ..."transports for free" ...
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t][.2\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    "venue", "date", "time"???
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]